# Moodle: install new plugin

Tags: plugins, moodle

When I try to install my plugin in Moodle , I face a problem that stops my installation:
You must solve all the plugin requirements before proceeding to install this Moodle version!

Comment: What plugin are you trying to install? What version of moodle? The plugin will list the names of other plugins required to make it work on the same page that gives you the error message you have seen (also it will state the minimum version of moodle you need)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at his discussion :

[You must solve all the plugin requirements before proceeding to install this Moodle version](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=263597)

(The Final Solution: try to download and re-install a new version of moodle)